# How to change request headers in .NETCore2 implementations

Tags: servicestack

For testing purposes I need to alter the Authorization header of an incoming HttpRequest - from Basic to Bearer (the processing is done in a ServiceStack plugin which acts during the PreRequestFilters phase).

This used to work in ServiceStack 4.5.x version (.NET Framework 4.6.2) but fails once I've upgraded the code to 5.0.2 and NETCore2.

Looking into the source code I see the NETCore implementation uses NetCoreRequest class for request implementation and NetCoreHeadersCollection class to implement the headers collection.

Unfortunately there's no way to alter the headers in the above mentioned collection, this is what I see in source code:

```
public override void Add(string name, string value) => throw new NotSupportedException();
public override void Clear() => throw new NotSupportedException();
public override void Remove(string name) => throw new NotSupportedException();
public override void Set(string key, string value) => throw new NotSupportedException();
```

Is there another way of altering the request headers before they hit the request filters and the service in NETCore implementation?

Thanks,

Emil Petrisor

Answer (score 0):

You can access .NET Core's Request/Response header collections with:

```
PreRequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpRes) => {

    if (httpReq.OriginalRequest is HttpRequest coreReq)
    {
        coreReq.Headers[HttpHeaders.Authorization] = ...;
    }

    if (httpRes.OriginalResponse is HttpResponse coreRes)
    {
        var authHeader = coreRes.Headers[HttpHeaders.Authorization];
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately that doesn't help me as I need to modify the request authorization header.

Comment: @EmilPetrisor I've updated the answer to include accessing the Request Headers as well.